# $\lim_{\vert z\vert\to\infty}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}=n\in\mathbb{N}$ implies $f$ is a polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

Let $f$ be an entire function, meaning $$f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$$ is holomorphic. If $f\not\equiv0$ and $$\lim_{\vert z\vert\to\infty}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}=n\in\mathbb{N}_0$$ then $f$ have to be a polynomial of degree $n$.

I was able to proof that $f$ can only have finitely many roots, using
$$\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}=\frac{z}{z-z_1}+\frac{z}{z-z_2}+...$$
where $z_n$ are the roots. Taking the limit this series diverges if there were infintely many roots. This also already proofed, that $f$ has exactly $n$ roots. Nonetheless doing this is only valid, if $f$ even has any roots.

If there are no roots, $f$ can not be a non-constant polynomial. So it's either constant or it is a transcendental entire function. So proving that $f$ can not be an transcendental entire function would imply the case what happens when $f$ has no roots.

I would appreciate any hints how to prove, that $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: In the case that $f$ has no roots, we get that $\frac{z f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is entire and bounded, thus constant (and in particular has to be $n$), this gives rise to a very simple differential equation whose solutions cannot be entire (they have a pole at $0$), thus we get a contradiction. this leaves you with the case of at least 1 root.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
 g(z) = \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}
$$
is meromorphic in $\Bbb C$, with a simple pole at each point $z \ne 0$ where $f$ has a zero. Since
$$
 \lim_{|z| \to \infty} g(z) = n \,,
$$
$g$ has only finitely many poles, so that $f$ has only finitely many zeros.

So we can write
$$
 f(z) = P(z) e^{h(z)}
$$
with a polynomial $P$ and an entire function $h$. (This covers also the  case that $f$ has no zeros at all, in that case $P$ is a constant polynomial.)

Then
$$
 \frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)} + z h'(z) \, .
$$
Now every polynomial satisfies
$$
\lim_{|z| \to \infty}\frac{zP'(z)}{P(z)} = \deg P
$$
so that
$$
 \lim_{|z| \to \infty} zh'(z) = n - \deg P \, .
$$
It follows that $zh'(z)$ is a *bounded* entire function, and therefore constant:
$$
 zh'(z) = n - \deg P \, .
$$
Setting $z=0$ gives $n = \deg P$ and consequently, $h'(z) = 0$.

So $h$ is constant, and $f(z) = P(z)e^h$ is a polynomial of degree $n$.

*Remarks:*

- As pointed out by Kavi Rama Murthy in the comments, it suffices to require that $L = \lim_{|z| \to \infty}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}$ exists (as a real number). The proof still works and shows that $f(z) = P(z)$ is a polynomial, and $L = \deg P$ is in fact a non-negative integer.
- If $f$ is *meromorphic* function in $\Bbb C$ and $L = \lim_{|z| \to \infty}\frac{zf'(z)}{f(z)}$ exists then the same method shows that $f(z) = P(z)/Q(z) $ is *rational* and $L = \deg P - \deg Q$ is an integer.

Comment: Can you please explain how g has only finitely many poles!

Comment: @LawrenceMano: If $g$ had infinitely many poles then they would accumulate at infinity. But that is not possible because of the limit condition.

Comment: So the given limit being an integer  is an unnecessary assumption. You have proved that it must be an integer.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Yes, it seems so. And if we allow $f$ to be meromorphic then the conclusion would be that $f = P/Q$ is rational, with $n = \deg P - \deg Q$ a (positive, zero, or negative) integer.